# Plot title containing math $\\times$ sign

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

I would like to include the mathematical sign for a multiplication (like the lower-case x) in a plot title.

I have tried using `latex2exp` to no avail - can someone help me with this?

The reprex code is this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
ggplot(data = data.frame(number = round(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5))),
       aes(x = number)) + geom_density() +
  ggtitle(TeX("Title containing times sign here: $\\times$"))
```

And it produces this outcome:

[image]

I would like the square (indicating an unrecognized sign) to display as this sign: [image]. It seems that other signs work (e.g. alpha) using this approach but I cannot figure out why the `times` sign poses an issue.

I'm not set on using latex2exp for the solution, as long as it works with the latex font (LM Roman 10).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you use unicode × with `"Title containing times sign here: \u00D7"`?

Comment: Great, that works! Thanks so much! :) (If you post this as answer, I can accept it and close the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to use the unicode code for the [multiplication symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(number = round(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5))),
       aes(x = number)) + geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Title containing times sign here: \u00D7")
```

Unicode characters can be added to any string with `\u` and the 4 hex code. You can find the appropriate code from your OS or with Google.

Answer (score 8):

It works for me with `plotmath` facilities:  the `%*%` operator displays as the times symbol.  For example,

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(number = round(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5))),
       aes(x = number)) + geom_density() +
  ggtitle(expression("Title containing times sign here: " %*% ""))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I think that is what `latex2exp` was trying to do, so it might be that on your system the times symbol was missing, which is why you got the box.  Funny that the Unicode solution worked.